# MediaPlayer Service not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, logcat

I'm using the following code for `MediaPlayer` services. But the following service is not running. The toasts are being triggered but the player doesn't play any song. 
The 'onStart()' method is deprecated as I override it.

```
package com.example.user.stringremoval;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bet);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(50,50);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

}



Error in Logcat:
06-27 12:47:03.175 3022-3022/com.example.user.stringremoval E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
    JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

Activity class:

```
package com.example.user.stringremoval;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AudioPlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button bn1,bn2,bn3;

    Intent intent1=getIntent();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_player);

        bn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

        bn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        bn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        bn3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button3:
                startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.stringremoval">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AudioPlayer"></activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Override `onStartCommand()` method and return `START_STICKY` have look this!

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // play mp3 code here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

refer [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm) for better understanding of above method and `START_STICKY`.
Hope it will help you!

Comment: It is not working..!! Tried overriding the onStartCommand() method too, it also doesn't play any song. @Hemant Parmar

Comment: @VibhorGupta is raw file is valid audio file?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid mp3 file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and define below things into your code..

```
// this line define into activity class into oncrateview method.

startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

add below line into android manifest file ..
between application tag..

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.my.packagename.MyService" />
```

Comment: The above startService() method has already been defined in Main activity. @Android Team

Comment: startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
this code put into oncreate method

Comment: I've edited my code. Kindly take a look at the same. I've already mentioned the startService method in onClickListener. @Android team

Comment: i have test app and it working i put audio file into raw floder and download audio file from this https://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-audio.php in first 0.4 mb.mp3

Comment: and it's play that file.

Comment: and this line add into android manifest file         <service android:name=".model.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

Comment: if it not add then server is not running.

Comment: I've added it in the Android Manifest file too..!! I've registered the service. @AndroidTeam Kindly check I've edited the code and have also included my Manifest file. but still its not working.

Comment: then check other audio files download from here https://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-audio.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173869/discussion-between-vibhor-gupta-and-android-team).